# lower semicontinuous of the convex function

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, entropy

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}$ be a convex set, $\phi :\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ be a convex function and $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence in $L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$ with value in $\Omega$.  Assume that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\|f_n-f\|_{L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)}=0\quad \text{and}\quad \sup_{n}\|\phi(f_n)\|_{L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)}<\infty.
\end{align*}
Can we show that
\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\phi(f(x))dx\le\varliminf_{n\to\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\phi(f_n(x))dx?
\end{align*}
Notice that the convex function $\phi$ may be negative, which makes Fatou's Lemma failed  . For example, if $f_n$ and $f$ are positive functions, and $\phi(x)=x\ln x$, we expect that
\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}f(x)\ln f(x)dx\le\varliminf_{n\to\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}f_n(x)\ln f_n(x)dx.
\end{align*}

Comment: When replacing $\mathbb{R}^d$ by any bounded domain, the lower semicontinuous of the convex function is well-know. In addition, assume that $f_n$ satisfying a uniformly moments or energy condition, by the properties of relative entropy, we also have the  lower semicontinuous of the function $x\ln x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, the claim is not true.

Here is a counterexample for
$$
\phi(x) = \begin{cases} + \infty & \text{ if } x<0\\
-\sqrt x &  \text{ if } x\ge0.
\end{cases}
$$
Set $f_n = \frac1{n^2}\chi_{(0,n)}$. Then $f_n \to 0$ in $L^1$, $\phi(0)=0$, but $\int_{\mathbb R}\phi(f_n) dx = -1$.

Similarly, a counterexample can be constructed for $\phi(x)=x\log x$:
take $a_n$ to be a solution of $a \log a = -\frac1n$ such that $a_n\cdot n\to0$ for $n\to\infty$, which is possible using the Lambert $W$-function. Then set $f_n = a_n\chi_{(0,n)}$.

---

Assume $\phi:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R \cup\{+\infty\}$ to be convex and lower semicontinuous.
If $\phi(0)=0$ and $\partial \phi(0)\ne\emptyset$ then the claim can be proven as follows:

Take $s\in \partial \phi(0)$, then $\phi(x) \ge sx$. Now apply Fatou's Lemma to get
$$
\int \phi(f) - sf \ dx
\le \int \liminf (\phi(f_n)-sf_n)
\le \liminf \int \phi(f_n)-sf_n \\
= \liminf \int \phi(f_n)dx - \int sf\ dx,
$$
the integral $\int sf\ dx$ is finite, so can be cancelled.
(Here, first inequality is from lower semicontinuity of $f\mapsto \phi(f)-sf$, second is Fatou's lemma.)

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. However, unfortunately, we don't know whether there is an $s\in \partial \phi(0)\cap\mathbb{R}$. For example, in my origin question, $\phi(x)=x\ln x$, it is easy to see that $\partial \phi(0)=-\infty$.

Comment: @alphabeta but $x \log x$ is not convex from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$, i.e., its domain is the set of non-negative numbers ($\phi(x)=+\infty$ for $x<0$).

Comment: @alphabeta added a counterexample

Comment: Thanks again for your construct. This question confused me for a long time. It is an interesting and concise structure!

Comment: However it remains to show that one set $g_n := \phi(f_n)-s f_n$ then $g:=\liminf_{n} g_n = \phi(f) - sf$ which is not clear without further hypotheses on $\phi$.

Comment: @mFriction Only $g \le \liminf g_n$ is needed. Which is true if $\phi$ is lower semicontinuous. Will add this asumption.

Comment: By the way, in the proof it seems that only the sub-differential at zero $s\in \partial \phi(0)$ is used and not directly convexity. Is there a hidden argument that requires convexity ?

Comment: yes, seems so. No convexity required.